# Shapiro-Wilk test calculation in SPI index

Tags: r, spi

I'm trying to verify if the SPI index follow the normal distribution with Shapiro Wilk test, but I dont know if I need to use $fitted and the $p.value or $w from Shapiro test or maybe need to convert the time series format to dataframe, like this:

```
install.packages("SPEI")  
install.packages("readr")
library(SPEI)
library(readr)

options(scipen=999)

df <- read_delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/victoresende19/testing/main/PRECPT.csv", 
                           ";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","), 
                           trim_ws = TRUE)


##### SPI #####
SPI12 <- spi(ts(df$`PRECIPITACAO`, freq = 12, start=c(1992, 1)), scale = 12)
plot(SPI12)

#Teste de normalidade
SPI_shapiro <- shapiro.test(SPI12$fitted)$p.value
```

The SPI Index must return index that follow normal distribution. But I think I am doing something wrong because the shapiro test is returning p-value 0.0019, rejecting H0.

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve], in particular tell us what package `spi` is coming from and give us an example precipitation series to work with?  (The [spi package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spi/index.html) was archived two years ago ...)

Comment: I haven't tried to understand the theory, but based on a quick search of the literature, it seems as though non-Normal SPIs **are** a possible outcome, i.e. you're not necessarily doing anything wrong ... ??? Wu, Hong, Mark D. Svoboda, Michael J. Hayes, Donald A. Wilhite, and Fujiang Wen. “Appropriate Application of the Standardized Precipitation Index in Arid Locations and Dry Seasons.” International Journal of Climatology 27, no. 1 (2007): 65–79. https://doi.org/10.1002/joc.1371.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clearly *not* distributed normally:

```
plot( density(df$PRECIPITACAO))
```

[image]

In fact this looks very similar to an earlier density plot I encountered on SO in the last week. And here is the density estimate for the fitted values:

```
SPI12 <- spi(ts(df$`PRECIPITACAO`, freq = 12, start=c(1992, 1)), scale = 12)
[1] "Calculating the Standardized Precipitation Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI) at a time scale of 12. Using kernel type 'rectangular', with 0 shift. Fitting the data to a Gamma distribution. Using the ub-pwm parameter fitting method. Checking for missing values (`NA`): all the data must be complete. Using the whole time series as reference period. Input type is tsvector. Time series spanning Jan 1992 to Dec 2022, with frequency = 12."
 plot(SPI12)
Warning message:
Removed 361 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`). 
> 
> #Teste de normalidade
SPI_fitted <- SPI12$fitted
 plot( density(SPI_fitted, na.rm=TRUE))
```

[image]

The other statistical concern is that these values are clearly NOY independently drawn from a distribution. The degree of auto-correlation is way to high for any consideration of these as IID.

Comment: But in this case you're using PRECIPITACAO variable, not SPI indexes (because you use PRECIPITACAO to feeding the SPI model), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Updating: Like some of you told me, I was not doing anything wrong, just don't choose the right parameters for my data considering the drought period of the data's location. The scale = 12 was not the best for my problem.